# sass error when run "ionic cordova build android --prod"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, build

After a few months building, I'm ready to make a new app-release of my Ionic app to publish it in the store. So far so good :)

When I run:

`ionic cordova build android --prod`

I get the following error:
[image]
And after the error, the build stops.

When I run:

`ionic cordova build android **--release**"`, no error! But I need the **--prod**.

*My configuration:*

I've an extra copy-script in the package.json:

```
"config": {
    "ionic_copy": "./scripts/copy-custom-libs.js"
},
```

The copy-custom-libs.js looks like:

```
const existingConfig = require('../node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/copy.config');
module.exports = Object.assign(existingConfig, {
    copyFontawesomeFonts: {
      src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/**/*'],
      dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/fonts'
    },
    copyFontawesomeCss: {
      src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'],
      dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/css'
    }
  }
);
```

My Ionic info:

```
$ ionic info

cli packages: (E:\LivelikecounterIonic3\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

    Node : v8.8.1
    npm  : 2.15.12
    OS   : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

I've tried the work-a-round found at: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/sass-error-after-update-when-running-android-build-with-prod/90087. But the same error. I hope hope you have a good idea.

Comment: Ai, what a shame. Probably a other time the complete scss-folder of fontawesome was copied in my assets folder, which Ionic correctly want to compile. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Ai, what a shame. Probably a other time the complete scss-folder of fontawesome was copied in my assets folder, which Ionic correctly want to compile. My bad.